# Can't install tomcat7 server into eclipse on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, tomcat7

I installed:

- Eclipse Kepler
- Tomcat7 at `/usr/local/tomcat7`

When I start tomcat `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` and go to `myIp:8080` I see [correct page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKOF2.png)

And now when I want to add tomcat7 at eclipse (at server view) I choose:

`add new server => choose tomcat7` the finish button is disabled.

[image: tomcat looking]

I can't figure out why this happen.

**How to solve this trouble?**

Comment: I am facing the same problem and returned to developing on my Mac because of it... did not find out what the hell is going on. Everything else works, except for Tomcat 7. It's crazy.

Comment: @scravy Which OS had you used? Ubuntu or differ?

Comment: The very same: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: @scravy Had you tried reinstall eclipse again?

Comment: I used an Eclipse version which I downloaded directly from eclipse.org, not from the package repositories. There for "reinstalling" is merely more than extracting the package twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/453143/

> close eclipse
>   go to {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings
>   remove the files org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs and
>   org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's disabled because "server name" is empty.

Comment: No you can not type in that field, I stumbled across the same problem and could not figure out what was going on.